# Youtube iframe API limited methods

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to use the Youtube iframe API to establish control to a prepopulated Youtube video embedded as an iframe on a page. I use it like this:

```
var player = new YT.Player("video1")
```

In most of the cases, this works perfectly well, however, in some cases I get back a player object that has a very limited number of methods (e.g. only 4 get methods `".getIframe", ".getOption", ".getOptions",` and `".getVideoEmbedCode".`). Has anyone experienced the same issue and knows a way out?

I noticed that I can provoke the same behavior, when there is a violation of the trusted origin parameter (e.g. with a reference to an iframe that has origin parameter http://exampleA.com but is hosted on http://exampleB.com), however, it doesn't seem to be limited to that, as in the case in question, there is no origin violation.

Any help or feedback is highly appreciated!